# How to know my gtk version on openSuse?

Tags: gtk

I want to know what version of GTK I am running on my openSUSE...
I heard I simply needed to use console.. But what kind of command should I use? Please answer when possible

Thanks in advance,
Tomás Simões

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pkg-config --list-all | grep gtk
```

In my case:

```
gtk+-x11-3.0                   GTK+ - GTK+ Graphical UI Library
gtkhtml-editor-4.0             gtkhtml-editor - HTML editor widget
gtkspell3-3.0                  gtkspell3 - On-the-fly spell checking for GtkTextView widgets.
libgtkhtml-4.0                 libgtkhtml - libgtkhtml
javascriptcoregtk-3.0          JavaScriptCoreGTK+ - GTK+ version of the JavaScriptCore engine
libcanberra-gtk3               libcanberra-gtk3 - Gtk3 Event Sound API
gtkmm-3.0                      gtkmm - C++ binding for the GTK+ toolkit
gtk+-unix-print-3.0            GTK+ - GTK+ Unix print support
gtk+-wayland-3.0               GTK+ - GTK+ Graphical UI Library
gtk+-3.0                       GTK+ - GTK+ Graphical UI Library
webkitgtk-3.0                  WebKit - Web content engine for GTK+
```

You can also include/link it into your code with pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --cflags / --libs

Comment: Surely this would only work if you have the development files installed (specifically the .pc file). You'd need a SUSE (or RPM) specific command to discover what version of GTK+ is installed for use by applications.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that would by why you wanted to know which version was installed. Since OpenSuse also works on a repository, you could use "dpkg --get-selections | grep libgtk" or, if all else fails, look under /usr/lib.